# How to extract subset of list of data frames and row bind them into one

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frames:

```
output <- list(structure(list(member = structure(list(name = c("Mick.HMSC-ad", 
"John.HMSC-ad", "Paul.HMSC-ad"), band = c("Stones", "Beatles", 
"Beatles")), .Names = c("name", "band"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L)), instrument = structure(list(
    name = c("John", "Paul", "Keith"), plays = c("guitar.HMSC-ad", 
    "bass.HMSC-ad", "guitar.HMSC-ad")), .Names = c("name", "plays"
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))), .Names = c("member", "instrument")), structure(list(member = structure(list(
    name = c("Mick.HMSC-bm", "John.HMSC-bm", "Paul.HMSC-bm"), 
    band = c("Stones", "Beatles", "Beatles")), .Names = c("name", 
"band"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), instrument = structure(list(name = c("John", "Paul", "Keith"
), plays = c("guitar.HMSC-bm", "bass.HMSC-bm", "guitar.HMSC-bm"
)), .Names = c("name", "plays"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L))), .Names = c("member", "instrument"
)))
```

In this case I have 2 lists, but in reality there are more.

Which looks like this:

```
> output
[[1]]
[[1]]$member
# A tibble: 3 x 2
          name    band
         <chr>   <chr>
1 Mick.HMSC-ad  Stones
2 John.HMSC-ad Beatles
3 Paul.HMSC-ad Beatles

[[1]]$instrument
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   name          plays
  <chr>          <chr>
1  John guitar.HMSC-ad
2  Paul   bass.HMSC-ad
3 Keith guitar.HMSC-ad


[[2]]
[[2]]$member
# A tibble: 3 x 2
          name    band
         <chr>   <chr>
1 Mick.HMSC-bm  Stones
2 John.HMSC-bm Beatles
3 Paul.HMSC-bm Beatles

[[2]]$instrument
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   name          plays
  <chr>          <chr>
1  John guitar.HMSC-bm
2  Paul   bass.HMSC-bm
3 Keith guitar.HMSC-bm
```

What I want to do is to extract `$member` element and bind them into one data frames resulting:

```
          name    band
         <chr>   <chr>
1 Mick.HMSC-ad  Stones
2 John.HMSC-ad Beatles
3 Paul.HMSC-ad Beatles
4 Mick.HMSC-bm  Stones
5 John.HMSC-bm Beatles
6 Paul.HMSC-bm Beatles
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `purrr::map_df(output, 'member')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `purrr::map_df` to extract the `member` element from each sublist, which will *row-bind the individual elements into a data frame* (?`map_df`) automatically:

```
purrr::map_df(output, ~ .x$member)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
#          name    band
#         <chr>   <chr>
#1 Mick.HMSC-ad  Stones
#2 John.HMSC-ad Beatles
#3 Paul.HMSC-ad Beatles
#4 Mick.HMSC-bm  Stones
#5 John.HMSC-bm Beatles
#6 Paul.HMSC-bm Beatles
```

---

Or a `dplyr` solution with `bind_rows`:

```
bind_rows(lapply(output, `[[`, 'member'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The traditional base R method with `lapply`, `do.call` and `rbind`. Extracting only the `member` part of every list and `rbind`ing them together.

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(output, function(x) x[['member']]))


#          name    band
#1 Mick.HMSC-ad  Stones
#2 John.HMSC-ad Beatles
#3 Paul.HMSC-ad Beatles
#4 Mick.HMSC-bm  Stones
#5 John.HMSC-bm Beatles
#6 Paul.HMSC-bm Beatles
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(output, function(x) x$member))
#           name    band
#1: Mick.HMSC-ad  Stones
#2: John.HMSC-ad Beatles
#3: Paul.HMSC-ad Beatles
#4: Mick.HMSC-bm  Stones
#5: John.HMSC-bm Beatles
#6: Paul.HMSC-bm Beatles
```